# Strange behavior of Tab closing policy

Tags: phpstorm

I set up option "Close less frequently used files" and I supposed it should close files which I change very seldom first. Instead PhpStorm keep closing files which I edit very often.

Is this some bug? PhpStorm version 2016.1.2

Comment: I would suggest posting this to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes providing some screenshots/screencasts proving the issue

Comment: That's over 1 year old version (20176.1.2). Would be great if you could check latest 2017.2.4 for the same.

Comment: @LazyOne Don't want to buy subscription. But in previous version I could see the same problem.

Comment: You may simply try it in trial mode (IDE settings are stored separately). My point is -- it may work just fine in current version. That's, of course, if it's a bug that needs to be fixed (or already fixed in a build that is newer than yours). I could not spot any obvious matches with my [quick search](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=Tab%20closing%20policy) that would fit your description (but I may have missed it).